# add library gone missing?

Tags: eaglecad

I am trying to start a new project and the entire library seems to have been deleted or something.  When I select ADD, I get empty page.

It was working fine last week and the only change to my computer since that time was video driver update.

I have tried uninstall and reinstall of Eagle 7.5 64 bits and the library is still showing empty. I think a setting somewhere got corrupted and the setting file was for some reason not deleted when I used uninstall.

I checked, the directory is set correctly, and the lbr directory is still full so I think Eagle program got borked.  Seems uninstalling and reinstalling did not help so there needs to be something else?

Comment: In the Eagle control panel, find where it says "Libraries". Right click on that and then click "Use all". Does that get them back?

Answer (score 2):

Basically what can happen when you create a new project is that Eagle will initialise a new project but with none of the libraries enabled. Once you re-enable them, it will store which are being used in the project file and remember for next time.

There are two ways of enabling libraries:

1. All at once

   You can enable all the libraries all at once by going to the Eagle Control Panel, finding where it says "Libraries" and right clicking on it, then selecting "Use All"

   [image: Use All]
2. One at a time

   You can enable libraries one at a time in the control panel. In the picture above, notice the little green circles next to each library. If the library is not being used, the circle is grey. If you click on it, it will go green and the library will be enabled (click again and it will be disabled).

   It is also possible to do it one at a time in the in both the Schematic editor and the Layout editor. In the editor, select where it says "Libraries" on the menu bar, and click "Use...". This will bring up a window where you can select one or more libraries to use.

   [image: Use One]

Comment: @Wilykat if this answers your question, please consider marking it as the answer. :)